# How to subract every element in an array from each other in C#?

Tags: c#, list, math, subtraction

I want to subrtract every element from each other, kind of like this:

```cs
List<int> list = [20, 4, 3, 7];
list = SubtractAll(list); // 20 - 4 - 3 - 7
```

And the desired output being:

```cs
6
```

How would this be done? Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: So, subtract items N, where N is in 1..list.Count-1, from item 0? Is that right? Are there any additional requirements? Like: what is supposed to happen, when `int.MinValue` is going to be underrun by the next subtraction?

Comment: What does `simple way` mean? A simple loop will do the job, eg `var start=list[0]; for(int=i;i<list.Length;i++){ start -=list[i];}`. Other options like LINQ eventually result in loops

Comment: Trivially, `int sum = list[0] - list.Skip(1).Sum();` or `int sum = list[0]*2 - list.Sum();`

Comment: To explain Matthew's comment: `a - b - c - d - ...` is the same as `a - (b + c + d + ...)` so you can just sum "everything after the first term".

Answer (score 5):

You can use Linq:

```
List<int> list = [20, 4, 3, 7];

var result = list.Aggregate((curr, next) => curr - next);

Console.WriteLine(result); // 6
```